# Using IIS URL Rewrite to redirect from the homepage

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

This feels like it should be really really simple, but I can't figure it out. I must be missing something very obvious.

I want to redirect from the homepage of my site www.example.com to www.example.com/coming-soon

but I can't figure out what pattern to use to match this. I've tried:

- keeping the pattern blank
- /
- ~

But none of these seem to match. I'm also not sure whether to match using reg ex, wildcards or exact match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex and for the URL field (top one) use '^($|default.aspx$)' (without the quotes).  That means exactly nothing or exactly default.aspx.  Obviously you can replace default.aspx with your own default doc.  Whether or not someone enters a trailing slash won't matter.  The URL field strips that.

You can use {HTTP_HOST} in the condition to filter by just your domain name.

And, if you use a rewrite rather than a redirect then the URL will remain at www.example.com and look a bit better to the user ... unless you want them to see the coming-soon in the URL.